# Sorl: Return the most recent offer for each document in a table

Tags: solr, cassandra

We are working with Cassandra and use Solr on top of it (DSE).
In a table `offers` we keep one offer per day for various documents which are identified by some buyerId. Each offer represent the different price which is changing each day so for each document we may have 30-60 offers.

How is it possible to find from all the documents in a buyer one offer per each document which has price lower than 10$ for example ... or even just to find for each document the offer which stands closest in time from the current moment

All the fields which are mentioned in my question are indexed.
The offerDate, offerPrice, buyerId, documentId etc.

For example we have all of the following for the same Buyer1 and we want to find the offer most closed in time:

```
document1
document2
document3
```

For document1 we have:

```
offer1Document1.documentId=document1
offer1Document1.offerDate = today.plus(5)

offer2Document1.documentId=document1
offer2Document1.offerDate = today.plus(6)

offer3Document1.documentId=document1
offer3Document1.offerDate = today.plus(7)
```

For document2 we have:

```
offer4Document2.documentId=document2
offer4Document2.offerDate = today.plus(1)

offer5Document2.documentId=document2
offer5Document2.offerDate = today.plus(2)
```

For document2 we have:

```
offer5Document3.documentId=document3
offer6Document3.offerDate = today.plus(3)

offer7Document3.documentId=document3
offer7Document3.offerDate = today.plus(5)
```

When we search for all the offers for documents of Buyer1 we will list ALL of the above results - 7 results.
How would it be possible to filter out the result so we have one offer for each document which stays closest in time and result is (only one offer per document with closest date):

```
offer1Document1.offerDate = today.plus(5)
offer4Document2.offerDate = today.plus(1)
offer6Document3.offerDate = today.plus(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the fields do you have indexed in Solr. We can construct the search query based on the fields.

Comment: All the fields which are mentioned in my question are indexed.
The offerDate, offerPrice, buyerId, etc.

Comment: Added info in my initial question about indexes and example use case.